# Ignore .NET validators if element is hidden (display: none)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

We often come into problems with .NET validators on elements that are hidden using javascript/css (ie. display:none)

For example (there may be syntax errors but don't worry about it)

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkNewsletter" runat="server" Checked="true" />
...
<div id='newsletterOnly'>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldEmail" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="Required" runat="server" />
</div>
```

with JavaScript:

```
$('#chkNewsletter').changed(function() {
  $(this).is(':checked') ? $('#newsletterOnly').show() : $('#newsletterOnly').hide();
});
```

It should not validate *txtEmail* if it is hidden.
You can't submit the form if *newsletterOnly* is hidden, because the RequiredFieldValidator is still effective eventhough it is hidden :(
And you can't even see the validator error message because it is hidden

Is there any way around this?

I am trying to avoid PostBacks to improve user experience.
I wish I could modify .NET javascript to validate controls only when they are visible.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the hidden elements? I'd _expect_ that to be the solution.

Comment: What about the possibility of using two different view models when posting to the server: one for each of the different situations? You would just need to post to two different routes.

Comment: Alternatively you would need to do your validation in the javascript, rather than on the server.

Comment: @ MAT GAL Disabling them using JS? I'd rather write my own validations then?
@Eli Not sure what you mean sorry. I've made the example clearer.
@ arcynum That's what I want to avoid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrote this as a general solution (can be used on all .NET websites).

You only need to add an OnClientClick to the submit button.

```
//===================================================================
// Disable .NET validators for hidden elements. Returns whether Page is now valid.
// Usage:
//   <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="DisableHiddenValidators()" />
//===================================================================
function DisableHiddenValidators() {
  for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
    var visible = $('#' + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).is(':visible');
    ValidatorEnable(Page_Validators[i], visible)
  }
  return Page_ClientValidate();
}
```

To use it, simply include the above javascript and add the class `OnClientClick="DisableHiddenValidators()"` to the submit button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="DisableHiddenValidators()" />
```

EDIT:
jQuery `$(submitButton).click` function didn't work on iPhone/Android. I have changed the sample code above slightly.

If anyone see anything wrong or possible improvements please comment :)

Comment: Unless I am doing somthing wrong. This disables all validators on the page. Even visible ones?

Comment: It shouldn't. Is the visible variable set correctly for you?

Comment: Magic: Thankyou! @aximili : a small modification added below to facilitate the ValidationGroup it resides in..

Answer (score 0):

It can also be a good idea to use Validation Groups in a situation like this. If you can group your validators then specify on the Button which validation group you need to validate against, only those validators in the group will be validated. Read more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227424(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Magic: Thankyou!

Modified slightly to include the ValidationGroup it resides in..

```
function DisableHiddenValidators(validationGroup) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        var isVisible = $('#' + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).is(':visible');  
        var isValGrp = (Page_Validators[i].validationGroup === validationGroup);
        ValidatorEnable(Page_Validators[i], (isValGrp && isVisible));  //Turn on only if in Validation group and IsVisible = true
    }
    return Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup);
}
```

To add Custom DisableValidators method to the click event tree:

$('#myButtonControlId').on("click", function(e) {  DisableHiddenValidators('Send'); });