# How to validate only which is visible in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, telerik, radajaxmanager

In my asp.net I am showing & hiding fields using css `display:block` & `display:none`

Now when I call `Page.Validate()` in my c# code, it validates all the fields and not only visible fields.

Well I know that I can do it by using "Visible=false" ot "Visible=true".

But problem is if it is visible= false then radajaxmanager cant find it & script dont work.

So how can I validate only fields which are visible & not all fields.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595908/ignore-net-validators-if-element-is-hidden-display-none

Answer (score 0):

Use this function in JavaScript to enable and disable the validation.

```
 ValidatorEnable(validatorid, true/false);
```

It works only if use **display:none** not for **visible=false**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `visible="true"` or `"false"` check the link of Rahul Nikate in the comments